# How to use React Component as custom control in Shaka Player?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, shaka, ott

I have a custom Shaka Player implemented with custom controls. Current controls are pure DOM elements, and I want to use React components instead. How do I achieve the same

Comment: If you can give some background explaining why you want to move your working solution to use React components and an example of one of your DOM control elements it may help people to answer.

Comment: I am using the shaka player in my react app. Reasons why I need React components as shaka controls is - 
1. I want to use reusable components from the app like <Typography />
2. I want to use some custom hooks to fetch data and update stream URLs
3. I want use redux to access some data like age Ratings, available list of Stream URLs, audio language options, also dispatch actions to redux store, to notify other components